# Tab Icons not showing on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I've been struggling to make tab icons show up on an actual Android device in a tab based application. It looks like icons cannot be found and all I can see is the tab text. Everything shows up fine though when running the app on the Android emulator. Has anybody had a similar problem and can give some valuable input? This issue happens only in actual Android devices, iOS works fine.

Dependencies used:

```
react-native : 0.49.5
react-native-navigation : 1.1.270
```

Code:

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
        tabs: [
            {
                label: 'Booking',
                screen: 'LocationsForm',
                icon : require('./src/assets/imgs/tabs/booking.png'),
                title: 'Booking'
            },
            {
                label: 'Account',
                screen: 'AuthSplash',
                icon : require('./src/assets/imgs/tabs/user.png'),
                title: 'Account'
            },
            {
                label: 'More',
                screen: 'Extras',
                icon : require('./src/assets/imgs/tabs/more.png'),
                title: 'More'
            }
        ]
});
```

**UPDATE**

For people that have the same problem. I could not find a way to make it work on an actual Android device when I was installing the debug.apk. The problem seems to solve itself though when you install the release.apk. So, all you have to do is assemble the production release of your app, install it, and you should be able to see the tab icons appearing fine on your Android device.

Comment: I am having this problem also, did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution found for making them appear under the debug.apk. If you install the release.apk instead of the debug.apk though to your actual Android device you should be able to see them fine.